# Dynamically allocate array without malloc & calloc

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
printf("Enter number of elements\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
int num[sizeof(int)*n];
```

Is this a right way to dynamically allocate array size?

Comment: More or less. `num` is a VLA (**v**ariable **l**ength **a**rray) and it's only valid within the scope where it has been declared. Google "C vla" for more information

Comment: Also if `n` is large it will overflow the stack.

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why not use `malloc` or `calloc`?

Comment: In other words: it can or cannot be a good idea to use a VLA. It depends on your use case. If you want more advice you ned to give us more information about what you're trying to achieve. Reas this: [ask]

Comment: Reword: are VLAs considered dynamic allocation? Answer: Ask your instructor; the answer could go either way. If their definition is simply any allocation based on variant run-time sizing, then yes. If their definition is the pure textbook mantra that the allocation has lifetime beyond the enclosing scope, then no. You could toss a coin, but if you want to rig the system, ask the person(s) adjudicating your answer.

Comment: Just remember that the memory allocated for `num` is not available after the function returns (just as with a fixed-size local variable).  In contrast, memory allocated by `malloc` or `calloc` is available until explicitly freed.

Comment: Also you're allocating `sizeof(int)` times as much memory as you need.  Hint:  You wouldn't write `int[sizeof(int) * 5]`, you'd just write `int[5]`.  This is no different.

Comment: @TomKarzes Doesn't adding static help with that?

Comment: You can't have `static` VLA for obvious reasons.

Comment: Don't forget to check the return value from `scanf()` before using `n` like that!

Comment: @Combospirit As Eugene said, you can't have a static variable length array.  How could you?  The size varies dynamically.  Try it.  You'll get a compiler error.

Answer (score 3):

The informal term dynamic allocation almost certainly refers to the formal term *allocated storage*, meaning heap memory returned from `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`.

Sure, there's other "dynamic things" around, like a stack which dynamically grows and sink, but we don't call stack allocation dynamic allocation.

Therefore it is impossible to do dynamic allocation without `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`.

---

What you have in your example is a variable-length array (VLA). They are allocated in run-time, typically on the stack. You use it incorrectly. You should

1. Verify that `n` is a valid value within a certain range 1 to max, before creating the array.
2. Allocate the VLA with `int num[n];`.

Comment: "impossible" without `malloc()` family... or some function outside of the C standard (e.g. `mmap()`)

Comment: Well, to be fair, `malloc` and friends are just user libraries.  You could implement your own versions, using `sbrk` to increase the data segment size, just as `malloc` does.

Comment: No it isn't relevant to speak of system-specific APIs here. Some systems might put the heap management directly in `malloc`, in fact that's how most embedded systems work.